# How to display immediately added data?

Tags: angular

I am adding data locally. And when I add, the amount of added data should show up in the badge component. But this happens only after switching to another page. And I need the data to be displayed immediately after adding.

How to do it?

```
quantity = 0;

ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout( () => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.order.list.length; i++) {
        this.quantity += this.order.list[i].quantity
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: Please include a snippet of html/view for the badge component so that persons may be able to see how you are binding data.

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising your data in the Component you've pasted a snippet of.

Components are able to share data (directly) by passing them to other Components (children) in their template - this is achieved by passing data to properties, in the child Components, annotated with a `@Input`-decorator.

Passing the data the other way (from a child to its parent) can be done by emitting events. Here, a EventEmitter is declared in the child component, annotated with `@Output`-decorator.

If you want to share data between Components without child / parent relationships - which could be Components loaded by the Angular `Router`, you can hold the data in a `@Service`-annotated class, that can be injected using Angular's Dependency Injection mechanism.

This is all explained (in great detail) in Angular's "Tour of Heroes" tutorial (which can be found here: https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: I have already made it so that the data is exchanged as I need. The data just isn't displayed in real time.

Comment: In that case, I think we need to see your template (and bindings)... It's a bit difficult to help without "the entire picture".

Is there any reason why you're wrapping the quantity calculation in a call to `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';

  constructor(private dtr: ChangeDetectorRef,){}

quantity = 0;

ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout( () => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.order.list.length; i++) {
        this.quantity += this.order.list[i].quantity
        this.dtr.detectChanges();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```